# How to downsample the .nii image?

Tags: matlab

I have an anatomical image, the size of which is as follows:

```
anatomy.nii: 
     Dimension(X*Y*Z): 256*256*124
```

And I also have an EPI image, the size of which is as follows:

```
EPI.nii:  
  Dimension(X*Y*Z): 64*64*40
```

I wonder if anyone knows the way of downsampling this anatomy.nii to the voxel resolution of  EPI.nii, such that the voxel resolution is matched between anatomy and EPI.

Comment: Are you asking for a possibility to scale  them in the UI? If so how do you visualize? If you want to manipulate the data and get a 64*64*40 for the first image as well, use `interpn`

Comment: @Daniel, I want to downsample the anatomy image so that I can overlay the EPI on the anatomy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%initialize interpolant, I has to be your war  data
I2=griddedInterpolant(I)
%returns interpolated image data
I3=I2({linspace(1,size(I,1),64),linspace(1,size(I,2),64),linspace(1,size(I,3),40)})
```

Comment: I type like this: I = load('structural.nii');
I2 = griddedInterpolant(I)
%returns interpolated image data
I3=I2({linspace(1,size(I,1),64),linspace(1,size(I,2),64),linspace(1,size(I,3),40)}).  But it does not work.

Comment: the error is : Error using load
Number of columns on line 2 of ASCII file structural.nii must be the same as
previous lines.

Error in test2 (line 6)
I = load('structural.nii');

Comment: @Angelababy: That's an issue loading the data, not interpolating it. I assumed you already managed this as you did not write anything about loading the image in your question. I suggest to check matlab file exchange, you will probably find a suitable function to load the format.

Comment: The parameter "I" should looks like what kind of format?

Comment: I tested it with a 256*256*124 matrix of doubles, which is the format I expected.

Comment: it means the parameter "I"  expects a .mat file. So I have to transfer .nii file to .mat file.